# How to take video with automatic watermark (PNG) and save it to video library?

Tags: xcode, video, watermark

How to show watermark on video while filming and save it as it shows on screen?

Comment: Etch the watermark into your camera lens?  You'll need to provide more context (and hopefully demonstrate some effort in having done your own research) in order to get better answers.

Comment: I mean - From App launch video camera, take video (while filming shows overlay watermark), save video to video library with this watermark. Watermark will be transparent PNG with 0.5 Alpha.